# Can't transfer error from Express backend to React frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

### Quick Background

I have a React component called 'Register.jsx' that allows users to create a username and password. The submit button sends the information to the Express backend and a row is created in a MySQL table that stores the usernames and passwords. In MySQL, I have the 'username' column set to unique values only and an error for duplicate entries is generated in Express...

```
{
    "message": "ER_DUP_ENTRY"
}
```

### Desired Results

I would like to display that error in the 'Register.jsx' component and allow them to retry it.

### Current Results

I can't seem to be able to retrieve the error message. When I hit the endpoint on Postman, I get the response, so I know the Express portion works.

### Relevant Code

**Register.jsx**

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await createUser(username, password);
        console.log(res)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setError(JSON.stringify(err))
      }
    }
```

**createUser.js**

```
try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/register', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        })

    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
```

**index.js**

```
app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
      const data = req.body;
      const username = data.username;
      const password = data.password;
  
      const query = `INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, email) VALUES ('${username}','${password}');`;
      
      try {
        const result = await connection.query(query);
        const res = JSON.stringify(result)
        res.status(200).send({ message: 'success'})
      } catch (error) {
          return res.status(401).send({ message: error.code});
      }
  
  })
```

### What I've Tried

I've tried all combination of JSON.stringify/return/console.log the caught & sent errors. I've tried to debug with `console.log(error)` to see what's going on. I've made no progress in 3 - 5 hours. I've tried using State hooks also, but since my console.logs are blank it doesn't really matter.

Comment: `return response`

Answer (score 0):

i usually use **axios** for API requests, but as far as i know, there is no error handler for API responses in fetch. So you can do it:

```
try {
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/register', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
  })

  if(response?.ok) {
     // Reponse statues are between 200 and 299
     return response;
  } else {
     // These are conflict,user not created etc.
     return new Error("blabla")
  }

} catch (error) {
  // These errors aren't API responses
  return error;
}
```